# What is the class definition of nn.Linear in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

What is `self.hidden` in the following code?

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(784, 256)
        self.output = nn.Linear(256, 10)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.sigmoid(self.hidden(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.output(x), dim=1)
        return x
```

`self.hidden` is `nn.Linear` and it can take a tensor `x` as argument.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> What is the class definition of nn.Linear in pytorch?

From [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Linear):

---

`CLASS torch.nn.Linear(in_features, out_features, bias=True)`

Applies a linear transformation to the incoming data: `y = x*W^T + b`

Parameters:

- **in_features** – size of each input sample (i.e. size of x)
- **out_features** – size of each output sample (i.e. size of y)
- **bias** – If set to False, the layer will not learn an additive bias. Default: True

---

Note that the weights `W` have shape `(out_features, in_features)` and biases `b` have shape `(out_features)`. They are initialized randomly and can be changed later (e.g. during the training of a Neural Network they are updated by some optimization algorithm).

In your Neural Network, the `self.hidden = nn.Linear(784, 256)` defines a *hidden* (meaning that it is in between of the input and output layers), *fully connected linear layer*, which takes input `x` of shape `(batch_size, 784)`, where batch size is the number of inputs (each of size 784) which are passed to the network at once (as a single tensor), and transforms it by the linear equation `y = x*W^T + b` into a tensor `y` of shape `(batch_size, 256)`. It is further transformed by the sigmoid function, `x = F.sigmoid(self.hidden(x))` (which is not a part of the `nn.Linear` but an additional step).

Let's see a concrete example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.tensor([[1.0, -1.0],
                  [0.0,  1.0],
                  [0.0,  0.0]])

in_features = x.shape[1]  # = 2
out_features = 2

m = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)
```

where `x` contains three inputs (i.e. the batch size is 3), `x[0]`, `x[1]` and `x[3]`, each of size 2, and the output is going to be of shape `(batch size, out_features) = (3, 2)`.

The values of the parameters (weights and biases) are:

```
>>> m.weight
tensor([[-0.4500,  0.5856],
        [-0.1807, -0.4963]])

>>> m.bias
tensor([ 0.2223, -0.6114])
```

(because they were initialized randomly, most likely you will get different values from the above)

The output is:

```
>>> y = m(x)
tensor([[-0.8133, -0.2959],
        [ 0.8079, -1.1077],
        [ 0.2223, -0.6114]])
```

and (behind the scenes) it is computed as:

```
y = x.matmul(m.weight.t()) + m.bias  # y = x*W^T + b
```

i.e.

```
y[i,j] == x[i,0] * m.weight[j,0] + x[i,1] * m.weight[j,1] + m.bias[j]
```

where `i` is in interval `[0, batch_size)` and `j` in `[0, out_features)`.

Comment: It is further transformed by the sigmoid function, as defined by x = F.sigmoid(self.hidden(x)). I can't see any sigmoid in nn.Linear class definition. Can you provide the source?

Comment: @AbdurRehman it is not a part of `nn.Linear`, it is just an additional step which makes the the whole mapping non-linear (making the Neural Network more useful and able to recognize more complex patterns, generally speaking).

Comment: Thank you for this. I was going crazy with the dimensions of the weights as I thought it was stored as in_features x out_features but it's transposed instead. Thanks for this awesome answer!

Comment: Sample calculations: `[1.0, -1.0]*[-0.4500,  0.5856]+0.2223=-0.8133` and `[1.0, -1.0]*[-0.1807, -0.4963]-0.6114=-0.2959`

Comment: @AndreasK. the first in_feature dimension and the last out_feature dimension are usually per-determined by our problem. But how do we determine the middle feature dimension. For example, in the above question, how was 254 chosen as the middle out_feature dimension.

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice that can be refined by experimentation.

Comment: I don't understand why they define the weight with shape `(out_features, in_features)` instead of `(in_features, out_features)`. If they define it like the latter then they don't have to transpose the weight before multiplying it to the input X. Is there any strong reason for why they do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `Network` defined as having two layers, hidden and output.
Roughly speaking, the function of the hidden layer is to hold parameters you can optimize during training.

Comment: Thanks, Can add more details like, which is `self.hidden`?

Comment: self.hidden is a Linear layer, that have input size 784 and output size 256.
The code `self.hidden = nn.Linear(784, 256)` defines the layer, and in the `forward` method it actually used: `x` (the whole network input) passed as an input and the output goes to sigmoid.

Comment: Also, not sure if it's not clear, but `hidden` is just a name and has no special meaning. It could be called `inner_layer` or `layer1`.